# Add on to the "about" URL protocol - FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox

If you don't know what I mean about the "about" URL protocol, then type `about:`, `about:startpage`, `about:config` into the address bar, also note that some of these work in chrome too!  Now my real question is, how do you add your own custom "about" protocol, e.g. `about:xeroelixir`, `about:example`, `about:custom` then have custom content for each of these?  Where ever I search on the internet I couldn't find a solution!

Also, might their be a way to add on to Google Chrome's URL protocol as well? ( Example of Google Chrome's protocol: `chrome://version`), but again, a custom one, `chrome://xeroelixir`

All that being said, it would not only be interesting to know how to do this, but it would be helpful for me, so thanks for any attempts to answer, or any working answers.

Comment: `chrome://` isn't "Google Chrome's protocol". It refers to the browser chrome, on which the name Google Chrome is based.

Comment: When I typed that into Chrome, it seemed to be valid? If it's some other url, feel free to correct me, and give me the correct protocol.

Comment: Well to be precise it isn't *just* Google Chrome's. Firefox uses it as well, albeit for a very different purpose. Chrome just happens to use it as a non-standard replacement for about:.

Comment: Oh, okay, because when I typed `about:` into Google Chrome, it redirected to `chrome://version`, but thanks for giving more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [registered](http://www.iana.org/assignments/about-uri-tokens/about-uri-tokens.xhtml) `about` URIs are: `about:blank`, `about:invalid`, `about:srcdoc`, and `about:legacy-compat`.
All others are vendor-specific / not registered (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme) for a list).

For Firefox, see the MDN documentation: [Custom about: URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about%3a_URLs). It contains a template which can be used to create your own `about` URL.